# Swapping tokens when value of sellToken is unknown

Tags: 0x

I want to swap from `0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8`(EURS) to `0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48` (USDC) but the `sellAmount` is not known upfront and is only known during contract execution.

I tried building the swap data using https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8&buyToken=USDC&sellAmount=277000. Passing it to the contract works if the contract has more tokens than the `sellAmount`.

How do I create swap data when the value of `sellAmount` is not known?

Edit: I don't know the `buyAmount` as well, I want to sell everything that the wallet owns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify either one of the `sellAmount` or `buyAmount`, or both. Since you don't have the `sellAmount` you need to provide the `buyAmount`.
[Link to relevant API Docs](https://0x.org/docs/api#request-1)

Comment: Sadly in this case I don't have access to either the sellAmount or buyAmount. I want to sell everything that the wallet owns at that point.

Comment: Like I said, you need to provide at least one of the two. You can get the balance of the wallet by using a web3 library like \eb3.js, ethers.js, or web3.py.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getbalance

Comment: Don't forget to subtract a bit from the wallet's balance for gas and fees.

Comment: I am aware of what the API requires, but my constraints don't allow me to know the buy or sell token amount in advance. Also, any web3 library is of no use because the balances change during the contract execution when I require swapping the tokens.

Zapper ZapIn uses ZeroEx contract to do the swapping when they don't know about the sell or buy token in advance but I am not sure how the tx data is created.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb07bb78395528985855812421ab714387ea5ec5fbb53e62ec6e96918ee46b618

Answer (score 0):

There is another flag `shouldSellEntireBalance` which if set to true would sell the entire balance up to the amount specified in `sellAmount`.

So in the above case, I had to do was ensure that `sellAmount` is greater than the amount in the wallet's possession and set `shouldSellEntireBalance=true` while fetching swap data.